# Git: the branch received in the pull request is dirty. how to clean it including git history

Tags: git, bitbucket

I received a pull request, but this commit history in branch(origin/foo) is so dirty, for example:

- It contains a commit named "test".
- It contains a lot of Diff like garbage, for example, just an indent, changed Single quotation into double quotation, and so on.

So, I want to clean this branch and commit history. Here are some idea:

1. clean up a lot of code in origin/foo, then commit.
2. delete this branch(origin/foo), and I create a new local branch(bar) from the starting point of origin/foo.
3. delete this branch(origin/foo), and clean up it in local branch(foo), then rebase it.

I think second is better, because it will not include some dirty code. However, I want to know a better way than these three option.

Comment: If you don't like the PR, reject it or send it back for improvements. It's not your job to fix it.

Comment: A rebase is the typical approach here.  Branch from `foo`, rebase interactively (git rebase -i main), squash or reword or fixup commits,  then you can compare that with `foo` to ensure you like the changes.   Rebase is a great option for cleaning up commit history and messages in prep for a PR.  And as matt said,  try to get to the point where your pr authors understand and can comply with your code quality standards